# How to read a file whose name includes '/' in python?

Tags: python, file

Now I have a file named `Land/SeaMask` and I want to open it, but it cannot be recognized as a filename by programme, but as a directory, how to do it?

Comment: Show us your code and error you received.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape forward slashes in python, so that open() sees my file as a filename to write, instead of a filepath to read?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014481/how-do-i-escape-forward-slashes-in-python-so-that-open-sees-my-file-as-a-file)

Comment: For a full discussion of this problem, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename).

Comment: try `Land\\seamask`

Answer (score 3):

First of all I recommend you to find out how Python interpreter displays yours file name. You can do this simply using [`os` built-in module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir):

```
import os
os.listdir('path/to/directory')
```

You'll get a list of directories and files in directory you passed as argument in `listdir` method. In this list you can find something like `Land:SeaMask`. After recognizing this, `open('path/to/Land:SeaMask')` will work for you.